# Strange problem with h5 and font smoothness/anti aliasing/bold

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have several h5 tags in my application. The last few days I implemented some major new features in my app and by chance I noticed that the h5 tags suddenly looks a bit "thiner"/pixelated than they used to.

Since I developed the new features locally I can easily compare with the production environment and its very clear something has made the h5 titles somewhat less bold/smooth/anti-aliased. I have been spending a lot of time trying to figure out what has changed but I just cant understand what has changed. When I inspect the h5 elements in Chrome and compare them to the prod environment they have the exact same styling, but still they appear different. I made a comparison image here: comparison

[image]

In the comparison image it is clear by looking at for instance the "D" in "Date format" that something is not right with the Bad one. It has two bumps that is clearly visible.

Would really appreciate some help what could potentially cause this and where I should look. I have been trying to narrow it done by removing pretty much all code from my app sequentially but still cannot understand where the modification is actually coming from. I am using the same browser with two different tabs develop vs prod. I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: It’s your computer’s subpixel rendering settings.

Comment: @RKazmi We should not be encouraging people to use `!important`. We should be teaching people to use rule specificity instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Subpixel rendering seems exactly the right technical term for this issue, thanks @Dai. Where do I change these settings and how can they have been altered? Are these settings by browser tab? Because as I mentioned in the prod environment the rendering works great which is open in the same browser instance just in a different tab.

Comment: Open Windows 10 Settings and type "cleartype" and in the search-results choose "Adjust ClearType text" - or go `Start > Run > cttune.exe`